# Infinite loop in my code and I don't understand where it comes from

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to learn how to use bisection search to improve the speed of a program I've written.
But it turns out I'm failing miserably. I've been stuck for 3 hours now going over my code, trying different things, googling, reading, and still nothing.
So I've come here, in the hopes that someone here can help me understand why my code is breaking and how I should think about not being in this situation again.

I'm using print statements where possible to see my output. And what I see is that it just repeteadly prints the same number (guess) without changing it. I'm thinking maybe it's because some variables scope is not in range (can't be changed?) and that might be my problem?

Here's the code:

```
def evaluatePayment(balance, guess, annualInterestRate):
    annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate
    balance = balance
    minPay = guess
    for month in range(1,13):
        remainingBalance = balance - minPay
        balance = (remainingBalance + remainingBalance * annualInterestRate / 12.0)
        #print "month: " + str(month) + " balance: " + str(balance) + " minPay: " + str(minPay)
    if balance <= 0:
        return balance
    else:
        return balance


annualInterestRate = 0.2        
balance = 320000
monthInt = annualInterestRate / 12.0
upper= evaluatePayment(balance, 0, annualInterestRate)/12
lower = balance / 12.0
guess = (lower+upper)/2
while True:

    if (evaluatePayment(balance, guess, annualInterestRate)) <= 0.00 and (evaluatePayment(balance, guess, annualInterestRate)) > -0.13:
        print "Lowest Payment: " + str(guess) + " balance: " + str((evaluatePayment(balance, guess, annualInterestRate)))
        break
    elif (evaluatePayment(balance, guess, annualInterestRate)) > 0.00:
        upper = guess
        guess = (lower+upper)/2
        print str(guess)
    elif (evaluatePayment(balance, guess, annualInterestRate)) < 0.00:
        lower = guess
        guess = (lower+upper)/2
        print str(guess)
```

EDIT:
Fixed indentation. It didn't look the same as in my file. I didn't paste the code the right way.

Comment: Indentation is important in Python; please review yours.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you for your input. do you perhaps have a small hint for me? Just to get me started on where to look

Comment: add indentation to your function's code. All the code to be included in the function should be indented after `def evaluatePayment(balance, guess, annualInterestRate):`

Comment: @PrerakSola Thank you for pointing that out. I overlooked the code and thought it would be pasted the same it looked in my file. Now I've redone the could and it looks exactly like the one in my file,

Comment: Can you tell, at which point it goes in an infinite loop?

Comment: @PrerakSola It seems to be stuck in the first elif statement. It just keeps printing the guess without it being changed.

Comment: Exactly, it modifies the value of `upper` in every iteration and this updated value is used no where. You are passing `guess` as an argument  in first `if`. The value of `guess` is never changed, so it returns false and goes to first `elif`. If you want to break the loop at first `elif`, include `break` like you did in `if`. And if you want your loop to break only when the first `if` statement is evaluated to `true`, than you need to update the value of `guess` in `elif`.

Comment: @PrerakSola Thank you! Like you say, I only want the loop to break if the first if-statement is true. I'm trying to update guess by writing guess = (lower+upper)/2 but it still doesn't update or leave the first elif statement

Comment: can you please update the code with the added statements?

Comment: @PrerakSola Okey, i've updated the code.

Comment: value returned from your function in first iteration is something `-5818` and it goes on decreasing around `-44964` in 15 iteration. As per this, your first condition will never be satisfied and so it goes in infinite loop. The value of `guess` does change in beginning but the change is very minimal. So after few iterations, you are getting a constant value. Try to check your logic in the function.

Comment: I did it! :D Man that felt great! :D
Thank you so much @PrerakSola!
I'll update the code with the right logic and answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem with the help of @Prerak Sola and by going over the problem by paper. Tried to solve it once by hand and everything made sense :D

So here's the updated code:

```
"""
This function evaluates the guess to see if it'll solve the problem.
It returns the balance so that you can use it.
"""
def evaluatePayment(balance, guess, annualInterestRate):
    annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate
    balance = balance
    minPay = guess
    for month in range(1,13):
        remainingBalance = balance - minPay
        balance = (remainingBalance + remainingBalance * annualInterestRate / 12.0)
        #print "month: " + str(month) + " balance: " + str(balance) + " minPay: " + str(minPay)
    if balance <= 0:
        return balance
    else:
        return balance

#Defines the variables needed for this to work
annualInterestRate = 0.18       
balance = 999999
monthInt = annualInterestRate / 12.0
upper= evaluatePayment(balance, 0, annualInterestRate)/12
lower = balance / 12.0
guess = (lower+upper)/2

"""
This is where the "guessing" takes part. It will iterate untill it finds a solution.
It takes the original guess and tries it, if it returns false it will check if the
guess was to high or to low and try assign new values depending on the elif-statement.
"""
while True:
    if (evaluatePayment(balance, guess, annualInterestRate)) <= 0.00 and (evaluatePayment(balance, guess, annualInterestRate)) > -0.01:
        print "Lowest Payment: " + str(round(guess,2)) + " balance: "
        break
    elif (evaluatePayment(balance, guess, annualInterestRate)) > 0.00:
        lower = guess
        upper = upper
        guess = (lower+upper)/2
        #print "high " + str(guess)

    elif (evaluatePayment(balance, guess, annualInterestRate)) < 0.00:
        upper = guess
        lower = lower
        guess = (lower+upper)/2
        #print "low " + str(guess)
```

Comment: removing `if ... else` from `function` and providing a single `return balance` statement would also work. It will optimize the code to a small extent .. :)

Comment: @PrerakSola Haha, funny thing is I was just looking at my code and thinking just that. It seemed kind of reduntant. But really appreciate the tips for optimizing my code. Can always strive to get cleaner, simpler and better code :)